# Nested setIntervals with different times OR calculate setIntveral on LCD

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create several different instruments, each with 1 or more measures, and all measures comprised of 1 or more beats.

An instrument has its own tempo, with the unit of BPM (beats per minute).   So if an instrument plays its 'song', the length/duration in ms is calculated by `numberOfMeasuresInInstrument*beatsInSingleMeasure/instrumentTempo*60.0*1000.0` 
beatsInSingleMeasure can also be referred to as a `signature`, since music is defined in units such as 4/4.

I am trying to loop a 'song'.  So if I have multiple instruments with varying durations, I want them to all start at the same time, and play till the end of their own 'score sheet', then wait until all instruments are done (ie the longest instrument duration) before restarting (this in effect is making each 'score sheet' equal in duration, and adding rests of an appropriate amount and tempo to equal the longest duration instrument).    So all instruments should start at the same time, and play their beats at the interval of their tempo, which I assume should be managed by another setInterval().

[Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/chrisfrisina/Qm2Tw/) is a fiddle to illustrate the durations with respect to each other. 
Let's assume that the first instrument plays for a duration of 2 seconds, the second plays for 1.6 s, and the third plays for 1.5 s.   That would make the first instruments beats play at an interval of every .66s, the second instrument's beats play every .4 s, and the third instrument's beats play every .25s.

How should I accomplish this? Conceptually it makes sense to me to nest the intervals, saying start every 2 s, and play your number of beats at the appropriate interval (first: three beats every .66s; second: four beats every .4s; third six beats every .25s;).  This seems easier than trying to figure out the LCD of the beat durations and playing them that way, since I would need to keep track of what is a beat or rest, and what is a filler to ensure it is in the LCD unit, in this case it is the LCD of .25, .4, and .66 => .01666 s (which is also 60Hz or 1/60th of a second)

Currently I have the following:

```
//Which beat are we on?  first ones are in the negative to allow the 'song'to buffer once through the 'song', required by HTML5 Audio buffer
var beatCounter = 0-(signature*measuresCount-1);
// How many measures?
var measureCounter = 0;
// Are we waiting on another instrument to play, because we haven't reached the maximum play duration
var waitCounter = false;
function calculateWaiting(){
  if ( beatCounter*dur == currentInstrumentDuration && currentInstrumentDuration < maxDuration ){
    waitCounter = true;
  } else {
    waitCounter = false;
  }
};

//This is the instrument interval
this.animationIntervalID = setInterval((function(self) {
  return function() {
    //this is the beat interval                   
    this.beatAnimationIntervalID = setInterval((function(self) {
      return function() {
        //if we have not yet played all the beats and are waiting on the 
        if (waitCounter == false){            
          // As long as we are still have beats to play, keep playing                                                                
          if (beatCounter >= 0 && beatCounter < totalNumberOfBeats) {
            //Get all the beats
            var beats = $('#measure-rep-'+self.measureRepModel.cid).find('.audio-beat');
            // If the beat is selected, ie not a rest....
            var selected = self.parentMeasureModel.get('beats').models[beatCounter].get('selected');
            //animate it
            self.audioAnimate(beats.eq(beatCounter)[0], dur, selected);
          }
          //Increase the beatCounter until all of the beats have played, then reset the beatCounter
          if (beatCounter < (totalNumberOfBeats-1)) {
            beatCounter ++;
          } else {
            beatCounter = 0;
          }
          calculateWaiting();
        } else {
          // Waiting until the longest measure is complete
          console.log('waiting until the longer instrument is done playing');
        }
      };
    })(this), dur); //dur is the cycle at which every beat should be animating/lasting
  };
})(this), maxDuration); //maxDuration is the cycle at which every instrument should be waiting for to repeat
```

So here is the shorter version:

```
//This is the instrument interval
this.animationIntervalID = setInterval((function(self) {
  return function() {
    //this is the beat interval                   
    this.beatAnimationIntervalID = setInterval((function(self) {
      return function() { ... };
    })(this), dur); //dur is the cycle at which every beat should be animating/lasting
  };
})(this), maxDuration); //maxDuration is the cycle at which every instrument should be waiting for to repeat
```

And a linear visual of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
//Scroll this window to see it linearly with time
// Let's assume that the first instrument plays for a duration of 2 seconds, the second
// plays for 1.6 s, and the third plays for 1.5 s. That would make the first instruments 
// beats play at an interval of every .66s, the second instrument's beats play every
// .4 s, and the third instrument's beats play every .25s.
// 
// The LCD of all instrument's beats is .01666s (60 Hz or 1/60th of a second), so it
// should look something like this: P meaning Play the beat, p, meaning the beat still 
// being sustained, I meaning the LCD interval, and W meaning waiting 
//
//    0s                            .5s                           1s                            1.5s                          2s
//    ^                             ^                             ^                             ^                             ^
//    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
// 1: PpppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppPpppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppPppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
// 2: PpppppppppppppppppppppppPpppppppppppppppppppppppPpppppppppppppppppppppppPpppppppppppppppppppppppWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
// 3: PppppppppppppppPppppppppppppppPppppppppppppppPppppppppppppppPppppppppppppppPppppppppppppppWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Comment: Do you want to do in real time, rather than a simulation?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a simulation, but the interval is for animations, that have to be mapped to the audio.   We calculate the time the animation should occur.   So I assume this means simulation.

Comment: Is there any reason why BPM (beats per minute) and bars aren't used instead of measures and beats per measure? And, what is instrumentTempo (how does it represent tempo)? And finally, what do a "measure" represent (a bar? measure of what if not) ?

Comment: How does your code not work currently? Can't you just calculate the maxDuration among all instruments, and on the start_playing of each instrument add one line `setInterval((function(self) {...play again..} , maxDuration`)`

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware What do you mean by `bars`?   Measures are used to show the idea of a whole, comprised of any number of beats, represented differently {rectangle, line, circle, or pulse}. The signature of an instrument is the number of beats in any single measure of that instrument, since all measures in an instrument will share the same number of beats, but may be different from instrument to instrument.   instrument tempo is the tempo of the instrument in terms of BPM (beats per minute), thusly directly also what BPM the beats of the instrument play at.

Comment: @foibs I do have the `maxDuration` calculated, but I am trying to have each instrument control its own playing.   But an instrument plays beats, so given the current structure, it makes sense to tell each instrument to play each beat (or rest) at its specified time given the instruments tempo (BPM interval)

Comment: @chrisFrisina bars in music is f.ex. a signature 4/4 => 4 beats = 1 bar. The reason why I ask is that I was gonna make an example and needed to map the terms.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware   try the fiddle, I updated it with math as well to make it make sense.